# ¿Cómo se centra un video que esta en un iframe?

Tags: html, css

tengo un `iframe` de un video de youtube, para centrarlo creo que tengo que ponerlo dentro de un `div` pero al css no se que ponerle para que lo centre

Comment: Pon el código que tienes hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es meterlo en un `<p>` por ejemplo:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
<iframe width="700" height="393" src="#" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</p>
```

De esta manera asignas el estilo de centrar el texto sobre el párrafo donde está contenido el iframe.

Comment: genial, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si te resolvió el problema, puedes marcarla como "Respondida" en el tick. Un saludo! ;-)